# "```" против "4 пробелов" для форматирования кода (python и не только)

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, ответы, редактор

В некоторых вопросах содержатся 4 пробела, для отображения кода, в некоторых ``` и/или `.
Мне думается, что для Python, Haskell и Yaml и т.д., где отступы являются частью синтаксиса, стоит использовать ```.

Что вы думаете на этот счёт?
Может стоит ввести какой-то один конкретный способ форматирования кода?

Т.к. в редакторе при нажатии CTRL + K появляются 4 пробела. также подсветка синтаксиса возможна (насколько мне известно) только в способе с кавычками, почему тогда не сделать эти два способа универсальными, читай "с одинаковым функционалом"?

Comment: Подсветка синтаксиса же есть в моих вопросах без кавычек. Или вы её не видите?

Comment: В обоих вариантах подсветка работает. Можно использовать любой вариант, какой кажется удобным. [Переправлять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/492150) в вопросах/ответах отступ пробелами на обратные кавычки **не нужно**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я лично использую ``` и всем рекомендую использовать:

- Другим проще править код
- Код можно вставить просто из своей IDE, и ничего жать не надо.
- Можно четко указать язык (e.g. ```python)

Но это чисто мое мнение и моя привычка, я ее никому не навязываю.

Comment: 2) А как IDE автоматически вставляет кавычки? 3) Зачем указывать язык?

Comment: 2) кавычки проще чем отступы 3) для улучшенной подсветки (для языков типа vb.net)

Comment: Подождите, вы руками пишите кавычки или IDE автоматически их вставляет? Если руками, то каким образом это проще нажатия кнопки? А подсветка для питона одинаковая в обоих стилях.

Comment: Не, сам ставлю...

Comment: Ну так кнопку нажать или комбинацию ctrl+K проще, чем 6 раз кнопку + кнопку перевода строки (это минимум, если вы заранее ставите две строки кавычек, а не первые 3 кавычки -> код -> вторые три кавычки).

Comment: @вася А мышкой ерзать ?

Comment: Ну так для нелюбителей мышек ctrl+K :)

Comment: @вася a code выделять?

Comment: Я вставляю код из IDE/online интерпретатора и он сразу уже выделенный. Ну либо ctrl+A для выделения всего текста.

Comment: @вася у кого как...

Comment: А нет, автоматически не выделяет, так что нажимаю ctrl+A всегда.

Comment: @вася А если у меня там уже другой текст?

Comment: Ну это зависит от стиля написания ответов. Я всегда начинаю с кода, а потом если надо, делаю текстовые добавки.

Comment: @вася А я наоборот или вперемешку.

Comment: поддерживаю автора ответа

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, допустим в сообщении сначала идет текст, после него идет код. Ставлю курсор между кодом, жму Ctrl-Shift-End, Ctrl-k, сохранить. Никакого лишнего ерзания мышкой.