# Почему при вставке примеров кода делается непонятный отступ вместо ``` с указанием языка?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Во время написания вопроса, автор может воспользоваться рядом средств форматирования, одно из которых – средство вставки кода (символ **{}**). Однако данное средство не удобно по ряду причин:

1. После нажатия на **{}** появляется сдвинутая строка с надписью *введите сюда код*, однако, если ввод кода производится вручную (да, все мы обычно копипастим, но мало ли), то при нажатии Enter автоматический отступ убирается и, следовательно, новые строки кода не будут распознаны как код. Ставить по 4 пробела на каждой новой строке в таком случае явно не удобно. Тем более, это будет сбивать с толку новичков, которые (как я, например, в своё время) ожидают, что если уж нажал Вставка кода, то всё написанное далее будет распознано как код без дополнительных танцев с бубном.
2. Если мы, опять же, нажимаем на **{}** и вставляем фрагмент кода, отступы проставляются для всего фрагмента. Однако, как только автору захочется сдвинуть одну строку во вставленном коде на строку ниже (встать перед ней курсором и нажать Enter), как весь следующий за этой строкой код, как и она сама, тут же перестаёт распознаваться как код. Это опять же приводит к танцам с бубном для исправления и непоняткам новичков.
3. Если автор вопроса вставил код и хочет поправить отступы для повышения читаемости при том, что код имеет большую вложенность, то он и так будет испытывать неудобство со "съезжанием" кода за границы окна редактирования, а намеренный отступ в 4 пробела, сделанный редактором кода, только усугубит проблему.
4. Язык не указывается явно, в следствие чего подсветка синтаксиса может работать неправильно или не в полной мере (с этой проблемой, в отличие от предыдущих трёх, лично не сталкивался, но, думаю, она имеет место быть).

Однако есть гораздо более удобное средство форматирования кода – символы **```**. С ними всё просто: поставил в начале и в конце, указал язык, если хочешь, и делай между ними всё, что душе угодно. Но, несмотря на удобство данного инструмента, он мало того что не используется как стандартный, о нём **никаким образом явно не сообщается новичкам**. В своё время я был поражён до глубины души, когда, редактируя очередной вопрос, увидел, что есть такое удобное средство, а я вот уже несколько месяцев пользуюсь этой *кривой* и *бесячей* (цитирую свои мысли в тот момент) стандартной разметкой.

Ввиду изложенного выше, возникает два вопроса:

1. Почему бы не сделать **```** стандартным средством вставки кода в вопрос? (Я себе это представляю как-то так: нажимаешь на **{}**, появляется список выбора языка с возможностью оставить его на автоопределение, выбираешь язык, если нужно, в окне появляются открывающие и закрывающие тройные **`** и между ними выделенная надпись *введите сюда код*).
2. Если нет возможности задать этот инструмент в качестве стандартного, разве не стоит каким-либо образом явно оповестить о его существовании всех, кто только начинает писать вопросы или ответы на SO?

UPD: наглядный пример того, как новичкам неудобно использовать стандартное средство (смотрите исходный вариант в истории правок): [Не могу запустить бота в дискорде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197515/344284)

Comment: Кажется, это где-то уже предлагали, но потерял где

Comment: Я тоже не знал о таком (```), спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10558/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be/10559#10559

Comment: @avp, Вот ещё очень полезная ссылка о том, как ставить метки языков (там внизу ответа список языков с метками): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/876852

Comment: лол, лично я не знал про `{}` и всегда использовал ```

Answer (score 11):

## Я за!

Это полезно для таких языков как питон, где отступы имеют большое значение. И вообще это удобней ИМХО.

[link](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10558/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be/10559#10559)

Answer (score 4):

В форме вопроса / ответа есть встроенный редактор кода `JavaScript/HTML/CSS`, который позволяет изменять отступы для **любого** кода, в т. ч. `Java` или `Python`. Там же ещё есть кнопка **Привести в порядок**, но она не всегда работает корректно.

1. Нажимаем на кнопку [image: кнопка специальная] ⇒ открываем редактор.
2. Копируем свой код в поле `JavaScript`.

   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - выделить всё.
   - <kbd>TAB</kbd> - увеличить отступ на 2 пробела.
   - <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> - уменьшить отступ на 2 пробела.
3. Выходим из режима редактирования без сохранения ⇒ **ОТМЕНА** ⇒ **OK**
4. Код с необходимым количеством отступов вставляем в сообщение.

Comment: это относится только к HTML/CSS/JS сниппетам, т.к. они могут воспроизводится в браузере в real-time. такого функционала нет ни у Python, ни к С#, ни у др. языков.

Comment: @return, нет, tab и shift+tab сработают независимо от осмысленности кода.

Comment: @Qwertiy это понятно. я просто: во-первых, констатировал факт того, что "такого функционала нет ни у Python, ни к С#, ни у др. языков"; во-вторых, что это явный костыль. зачем мне в редакторе JS делать отступы для C#? ну бред же!

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, я обычно, используя `````, tab'ю и shift-tab'ю прямо в редакторе (у меня это VS или VS Code). плюсы: отступ задаёте вы, что для меня must have, т.к. я привык к отступу 4, а не 2. после shift-tab'ония просто tab'аем обратно к прежнему виду кода.